# list query using if and .split() taking too long Python

Tags: python

Sorry if something along these lines has already been answered.

I am trying to find values in the list that are "after" 2004q2 (where 2004 is the year and 2 is the quarter.) I was looking for members of the list either in a year after 2004 or in 2004 but after quarter 2. To do this I tried the following code:

```
get_recession_start() is a separate function that returns '2004q2'
(changed value cause online class question)

def get_recession_start():
        return '2004q4'

two_q_growth =['2000q1', '2000q2', '2000q3', '2000q4', '2001q1', '2001q2', '2001q3',
 '2001q4', '2002q1', '2002q2', '2002q3', '2002q4', '2003q1', '2003q2', '2003q3', '2003q4',
 '2004q1', '2004q2', '2004q3', '2004q4', '2005q1', '2005q2', '2005q3', '2005q4', '2006q1', 
 '2006q2', '2006q3', '2006q4', '2007q1', '2007q2', '2007q3', '2007q4', '2008q3', '2009q4', 
 '2010q1', '2010q2', '2010q3', '2010q4', '2011q1', '2011q2', '2011q3', '2011q4', '2012q1',
 '2012q2', '2012q3', '2012q4', '2013q1', '2013q2', '2013q3', '2013q4', '2014q1', '2014q2',
 '2014q3', '2014q4', '2015q1', '2015q2', '2015q3', '2015q4', '2016q1', '2016q2']


for year in two_q_growth:
    start_year = get_recession_start().split('q')[0]
    start_q = get_recession_start().split('q')[1]
    if ((year.split('q')[0] > start_year)
        | ((year.split('q')[0] == start_year) &
        (year.split('q')[1] > start_q))):
        recession_end.append(year)
```

This code has been taking forever and a day to run and I am not sure why. (I'm still new to Python and trying to figure out how to optimize things.)

Thanks!

Technically I just need the first value so I am working on writing something with break but I would like to get this faster too

Comment: `|` and `&` are bitwise OR and AND, for logical (boolean) variant use `or` and `and`.

Comment: @randomir It shouldn't matter but I agree with you.

Comment: The code works "fine" for me in the sense that it populates `recession_end` list (after I set it to an empty list before the loop - this is not in your code).

Comment: It shouldn't (and it doesn't), but it's wrong. :)

Comment: Note that there's no memoization in Python for function calls. Repeated calls to `split()` with the same data object will re-evaluate the split. Store your intermediate results in variables. That said, this should not make that much of a difference, here.

Comment: It works on my machine (tm). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it should work, your code is incredibly inefficient and seriously overcomplicated. You don't even need to parse your array as in this case even string comparison would work just fine:

```
two_q_growth = ['2000q1', '2000q2', '2000q3', '2000q4', '2001q1', '2001q2', '2001q3',
                '2001q4', '2002q1', '2002q2', '2002q3', '2002q4', '2003q1', '2003q2',
                '2003q3', '2003q4', '2004q1', '2004q2', '2004q3', '2004q4', '2005q1',
                '2005q2', '2005q3', '2005q4', '2006q1', '2006q2', '2006q3', '2006q4',
                '2007q1', '2007q2', '2007q3', '2007q4', '2008q3', '2009q4', '2010q1',
                '2010q2', '2010q3', '2010q4', '2011q1', '2011q2', '2011q3', '2011q4',
                '2012q1', '2012q2', '2012q3', '2012q4', '2013q1', '2013q2', '2013q3',
                '2013q4', '2014q1', '2014q2', '2014q3', '2014q4', '2015q1', '2015q2',
                '2015q3', '2015q4', '2016q1', '2016q2']

recession_start = '2004q2'  # get all entries after this one
recession_end = [year for year in two_q_growth if year > recession_start]

print(recession_end)
```

resulting in:

```
['2004q3', '2004q4', '2005q1', '2005q2', '2005q3', '2005q4', '2006q1', '2006q2', '2006q3',
'2006q4', '2007q1', '2007q2', '2007q3', '2007q4', '2008q3', '2009q4', '2010q1', '2010q2',
'2010q3', '2010q4', '2011q1', '2011q2', '2011q3', '2011q4', '2012q1', '2012q2', '2012q3',
'2012q4', '2013q1', '2013q2', '2013q3', '2013q4', '2014q1', '2014q2', '2014q3', '2014q4',
'2015q1', '2015q2', '2015q3', '2015q4', '2016q1', '2016q2']
```

And if you only need the first value after your `recession_start` value, assuming your list is sorted (and if not run it through `sorted()` first):

```
recession_start = '2004q2'  # get the entry after this one
recession_end = None  # just in case we don't find it
for year in two_q_growth:  # loop through the list
    if year > recession_start:  # grab the first value higher than recession_start
        recession_end = year  # store it to recession end
        break  # break away, no need to loop further as we only want the first element

print(recession_end)
# 2004q3
```

Comment: Your condition `if year > recession_start` is not equivalent to the one in the original post.

Comment: @AGNGazer - and neither it should be - the one from the original post is probably the most inefficient way to do this as Pythonically possible.

Comment: You are selecting different values from the ones the original poster gets. Either he does not know what he wants or your condition is incorrect.

Comment: @AGNGazer - He stated in his question that he wants the value after `2004q2` and that's what the above code does. In his inefficient and overly complicated code he defines `2004q4` as the recession start which is why our codes will produce different results - if you set his recession start to `2004q2` (or mine to `2004q4`) the results will be identical, except that mine will execute in a fraction of a fraction of the time it takes to execute his (or yours for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this up by assigning year.split('q') to a variable instead of calling the split function every time. Try this

```
for year in two_q_growth:
    start_year, start_q = get_recession_start().split('q')
    year_split = year.split('q')
    if ((year_split[0] > start_year) or
        ((year_split[0] == start_year) and (year_split[1] > start_q))):
        recession_end.append(year)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

# convert your data to 2D numpy array of integer numbers (year, quarter):
two_q_growth_arr = np.array([map(int, x.split('q')) for x in two_q_growth])

# Pull start_year and start_q computation out of the loop:
start_year, start_q = list(map(int, get_recession_start().split('q')))

# find indices of all data that satisfy your criteria:
ind = np.where((two_q_growth_arr[:, 0] > start_year) | ((two_q_growth_arr[:, 0] == start_year) & (two_q_growth_arr[:, 1] > start_q)))

# Extract the years as a list of integer numbers:
recession_end = two_q_growth_arr[ind][:,0].tolist()

# or, alternatively, convert to a list of strings:
recession_end = list(map(str, two_q_growth_arr[ind][:,0].tolist()))
```

Another option is to convert years and quarters to a single fractional year which then simplifies the condition:

```
import numpy as np
two_q_growth_arr = np.array([map(int, x.split('q')) for x in two_q_growth])
two_q_growth_arr = two_q_growth_arr[:, 0] + 0.25 * (two_q_growth_arr[:, 1] - 1.0)
ind = np.where(two_q_growth_arr[:, 0] > start_year)
recession_end = list(map(str, two_q_growth_arr[ind][:,0].tolist()))
```